# aura:valueChange listener for property inside an array

Tags: lightning

Assume the following definition:

```
<aura:attribute name="objects" type="Object[]"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.objects}" action="{!c.setDirty}" />
```

The c.setDirty is not triggered if we change one of the properties of an element of the array. What is the correct way to listen to changes to each of the objects composing the array?

Comment: bind this action with the blur event handler. No other way.

Comment: On which node? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Let suppose now you are binding the `object` property with some text field so on this text field bind the blur/change event and link the `setDirty` method this that event

Comment: So if I am binding 10 text fields on each element I would need to specify the blur handler on each of the text field ui:inputText for example

Comment: Yes if you are binding that then you need to do that.